# slow performance of update statistics if iterating over several statistics of a table instead of updating all statistics

Tags: sql-server, database-optimization

maybe someone here can help me - I'm pretty stuck:

Today I started building a SSIS package, which should take over the task of evaluating the statistics of numerous tables and perform an update on these statistics. Most of the tables are indexed by a clustered columnstore index. Now, since the CCI is updated in another SSIS package, the corresponding statistic (same name as CCI) is refreshed in this package as well. So, my idea was to use the syntax

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [MyTable] [MyStatistic]
```

for each statistic except the ones named the same way as the CCI instead of using

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [MyTable]
```

which would update all statistics. This approach works, BUT it is way slower than the second syntax. Now I wonder: why is the update of all statistics faster than the update of the specific statistics???

Comment: If you can't repro this consistently,i assume you might be facing locking/blockings

Comment: It is reproducable. We have one package, which executed the update on all statistics of the required tables and it takes only half as long as the package which executes the update on the explicit statistics...

Comment: Please include  DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps